# Site body not changing color

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the hiero theme in WordPress and I'm using the custom CSS plugin.

This is what was in my style sheet:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
    background: #e5f2ff;
}
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
    background: ##c32026;
}
```

And the background remains white.

I am also trying to make the body behind the posts and content be a different color than the side bars.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: `##c32026` should be `#c32026`

Comment: `##c32026` is an invalid HEX color use only one `#`. By saying *"remains white"*... makes no sense cause it was never white, at least judging by the earlier `#e5f2ff`

Comment: oh WOW, i am an idiot. that did the trick - not sure why i had 2 hashes.

Comment: Also I am trying to make the post backgrounds and widget backgrounds a different color from the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background: ##c32026;` to `background: #c32026;`. You've got an extra `#` in your hex color, thus, it's invalid.

For the different colors in the widget and content area, you need to add CSS, like so:

```
#primary {
    background: #ccc;
}

#widget-area-2 {
    background: #333;
}
```

Just change the hex values to the colours that you want. This is assuming that these areas have the same `id`s as they have in the Hiero demo. If not, you'll need to find the `id`s for these areas in your instance of the theme.

Comment: yes now i am trying to make the sidebars different colors

Comment: @hefoundthekey I've added that info to my answer.

Comment: awesome! that worked. now im just trying to figure out how to extend the color all the way to the head and down to the footer so that i dont have a weird border around it

Comment: `#main {  padding-bottom: 0; }` Any other question should be asked separately, and show the work you've done to try to solve the issue. And, don't forget to accept the answer that best resolves you problem.